# MongoDB save same data repeatedly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have many number of documents in my collection i want to save same data by changing only one field i.e. "date" (which will be current time) repeatedly in the Mongo database.so how can i do this in mongodb.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you want to insert a new document or to update an existing document. The meaning of the word "save" depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to update only one filed of your document. You don't need to rewrite whole document:

```
collection.update({"_id": docId}, {$set: {"date": someDate }})
```

Consider also to use [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator if you want to set some field to current date value:

```
collection.update({"_id": docId}, {$currentDate: {"date": true }})
// or 
collection.update({"_id": docId}, {$currentDate: {"date": { "$type": "timestamp" }}})
```